# 2d array that looks for the most repeated number within the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, 2d

I did try using an if/else statement which I left in but commented out so you can still see it. I realized the problem with the if/else is not only is it a brute force method but I don't think I'm covering every possible case. I figured there had to be a more elegant loop solution, but loops have never been my strong suit and I need help with writing it.

```
public class stuff {
    public static int getMostRepeatedNumber(int[][] array) {

        int num = 100;

        if(array.length == 0){
            num = -1;
        }

        int [] numberOfTimes = new int[9];

            for(int i = 0; array.length > i; i++){
                for(int j = 0; array[i].length > j; j++){

                if(array[i][j] == 0){
                      numberOfTimes[0]++;
                }
                else if(array[i][j] == 1){
                     numberOfTimes[1]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 2){
                    numberOfTimes[2]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 3){
                    numberOfTimes[3]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 4){
                    numberOfTimes[4]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 5){
                    numberOfTimes[5]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 6){
                    numberOfTimes[6]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 7){
                    numberOfTimes[7]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 8){
                    numberOfTimes[8]++;

                }else if(array[i][j] == 9){
                    numberOfTimes[9]++;

                }
            }
        }



            for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++){

                while(numberOfTimes[x] > numberOfTimes[x+1]){
                     num = x;
                     break;
                }


                   /* if(numberOfTimes[x] >= numberOfTimes[x+1] ){
                     num = 0;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+1] >= numberOfTimes[x+2]){
                    num = 1;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+2] >= numberOfTimes[x+3]){
                    num = 2;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+3] >= numberOfTimes[x+4]){
                    num = 3;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+4] >= numberOfTimes[x+5]){
                    num = 4;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+5] >= numberOfTimes[x+6]){
                    num = 5;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+6] >= numberOfTimes[x+7]){
                    num = 6;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+7] >= numberOfTimes[x+8]){
                    num = 7;

                }else if(numberOfTimes[x+8] >= numberOfTimes[x+9]){
                    num = 8;

                }

                else{
                    num = 9;

                }*/
            }

        return num; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- An array that has 100 rows such that each row is empty is an empty array; your program returns 100 in cases like that. You do not need a special case for that if you structure your program correctly.
- Since you have single-digit positive numbers, all you need is an array of ten counts:

---

```
int[] counts = new int[10];
for (int r = 0 ; r != array.length ; r++) {
    for (int c = 0 ; c != array[r].length ; c++) {
        counts[array[r][c]]++;
    }
}
```

At this point, you've got an array of ten counters. Look for the highest one:

```
int max = 0;
int val = -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > max) {
         max = counts[i];
         val = i;
    }
}

// If you did not see any number because the array was empty, val remains -1.
System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: You have to look for the smallest candidate if there is a tie.

Comment: I already left a comment, and even got a response. I am removing the downvote.

Comment: Unfortunately, my vote is locked in, because it has been too long since I downvoted. Sorry.

Comment: @tbodt Hey, I don't like that fast locking timer either :)

Comment: @tbodt I know why (it's to discourage "tactical downvotes") I just don't like the time window being so short.

Comment: This was genius. Thank you so much, now I know where I went wrong.

Comment: What about 2d array ? How can I find in 2d array any help much appreciated. Please help

Comment: @ArpitPatel the code is searching a 2d array. See nested loops at the top.

Comment: Thank you for reply @dasblinkenlight  can you explain me  what is r ,c and i in for loop?

Comment: @ArpitPatel row, column, and index into `counts`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the first if-else thing with this line of code:

```
numberOfTimes[array[i][j]]++;
```

As for your problem, you can use this code:

```
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0, i > numberOfTime.length, i++)
    if (numberOfTimes[i] > max) {
        max = numberOfTimes[i];
        num = i;
    }
```

It loops over the array looking for the biggest value, which is stored in `max`. It also stores the array index of the largest value in `num`, which is the final result.

Answer (score 0):

If we're not guaranteed that the numbers are between 0 and 9,can it be done with less than 3 loops,like I did below

```
    int maxCounter =0;
    int counter = 0;
    int currentElementRow = 0, currentElementCol = 0;
    int maxOccurrence = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < arr.length * arr[0].length; k++){ //traverse the matrix as many times as elements you have in it- you check each element for number of occurrences
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++){
                if(arr[i][j] == arr[currentElementCol][currentElementCol]){
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter > maxCounter){
            maxCounter = counter;
            counter = 0;
            maxOccurrence = arr[currentElementRow][currentElementCol];
        }
        if(currentElementCol <arr[0].length - 1){
            currentElementCol++;
        }
        else{
            currentElementCol = 0;
            currentElementRow++;
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your first loops can be simplified as simply:

```
for(int i = 0; array.length > i; i++){
    for(int j = 0; array[i].length > j; j++){
        numberOfTimes[array[i][j]]++;
    }
}
```

.... because you have a pre-written guarantee that the values in the 2D array are between 0 and 9 (inclusive)